# Clear array of strings

Tags: c#, string

What is the easiest way to clear an array of strings?

Comment: clear an array? what do you mean be `clear`?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Have you tried [`Array.Clear`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.clear.aspx)?

```
string[] foo = ...;
Array.Clear(foo, 0, foo.Length);
```

Note that this *won't* change the size of the array - nothing will do that. Instead, it will set each element to null.

If you need something which can *actually* change size, use a `List<string>` instead:

```
List<string> names = new List<string> { "Jon", "Holly", "Tom" };
names.Clear(); // After this, names will be genuinely empty (Count==0)
```

Comment: Thanks!  I couldn't understand why I couldn't find clear under string methods.  The answer, of course, is that it's an array method.

Comment: I should probably know this by now but if you just set the string array to null does that free up the memory or do you have to call `Array.Clear` ?

Comment: @CodeBlend: Neither. You don't set an array to `null` - you set a *variable* to null. When there are no live references to the array, it will be *eligible* for garbage collection (but won't be immediately GC'd). If there are elements within that array which are *only* referred to by that array, they're eligible for garbage collection too.

Answer (score 9):

```
Array.Clear(theArray, 0, theArray.Length);
```

Comment: That won't compile - Clear isn't an instance method, and it isn't parameterless either.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on circumstance (like: what is in the array) but the best method usually is to create a new one. Dropping all references to the old one.

```
 MyType[] array = ...
 ....

 array = new MyType[size];
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can also get away with this for example:
    SearchTerm = new string[]{};

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
result = result.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Intellicode showed me to use

`aStringArray = Array.Empty<string>();`

Answer (score -2):

string[] foo;

foo = string[""];

Answer (score -2):

how about

```
string[] foo;
foo = null;
```